# Is it possible to export GeoTIF current view to GeoTIFF with QGis?

Tags: qgis, geotiff-tiff

ArcGis offers this, but I didn't found such a function in Qgis. Maybe I have simply not found the command.... Does someone know the command or is there an extenstion which offers such a functionality?

Answer (score 3):

Sisyphos: If you go to File > Save as Image, you can save the current view to a number of formats, and tiff is one of the options.

Comment: You can try this route but the resolution is limited by your monitor's resolution.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately it is limited to screen resolution.  I would love it if this were given attention in a future release.  I see that it has a ticket in the developer's forum, but no plan on implementation. :(

Answer (score 3):

`Raster -> Extraction -> Clipper` should do what you want.

Make sure that layer CRS and project CRS are the same, then start the clipping dialogue, and draw a rectangle of the current view.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a couple options I just tested in QGIS 2.14 (similar in QGIS 2.16).

You can use the instruction in this [post by Anita Graser](https://anitagraser.com/2010/11/30/creating-high-resolution-images-using-qgis/), using the OS console.

Or maybe a more intuitive way using the map composer. Add a map to the composer, go to Composition, then set the Exprot settings and finally save as image. Your image will have a world map containing the georeferencing for the image. see the attached image for an example on the settings

It seems that in QGIS 2.16 the image can be saved as GeoTIFF and georeferenced PDF, see the [QGIS 2.16 changelog](http://www.qgis.org/fi/site/forusers/visualchangelog216/index.html#feature-georeference-outputs-eg-pdf-from-composer)).

[image: Example settings to export map as image]